# How do I connect ActionScript 3 code to a Windows Service?

Tags: actionscript-3, windows-services

I have an AS3 application, and a Windows Service running in the local network, how can I connect the AS3 App to the Windows Service running in the other PC?

If the question is pretty vague it's because I don't have a clue on how/what the possibilities are and I'd like to know what should I search/look for, any hints are appreciated.

If this isn't possible, what would be a good course of action?

Answer (score 0):

I would assume you are talking about AIR desktop development, for Flash there is no such possibility. You should have a look at AIR native extention, which supports desktop environment. Basically, your app talks to the native extension, which then talks to OS.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS597e5dadb9cc1e0253f7d2fc1311b491071-8000.html